# what's the most efficient way to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, field-theory, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

When looking for Jordan canonical form of a matrix lets say $\begin{pmatrix} 2 &0 &0\\0 &5 &0\\1&2&2 \end{pmatrix} $ for simplicity.

It's easy to calculate the characteristic polynomial $c_A(x):=\det(xI-A)=\begin{pmatrix}(x-2)&0&0 \\0 &(x-5)&0\\-1&-2&(x-3)\end{pmatrix}=(x-2)^2(x-5)$.

so we know the possible minimal polynomials are $m_a(x)=(x-2)^d(x-5)$, where $1\leq d \leq2$.

and that the unique minimal polynomial must satisfy $m(A)=0$. This is a pretty straightforward matrix so it's easy enough to check both cases. But for larger matrices checking all the cases by process of elimination can be a long process. Is there anyway to make an educated guess on what the minimal polynomial will be without just checking all the possible cases ?

P.S. The matrix I've given here was only a basic example I used to elucidate what I meant. I'm seeking tips and tricks that could apply to any general matrix.

Comment: As you mention Jordan canonical form, it is easy to compute the minimal polynomial of a matrix which is written in Jordan canonical form.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm talking about finding the jordan canonical form of an arbitrary matrix

Comment: Not sure to have a clear idea of what you’re asking for. At least you don’t need the minimal polynomial to compute Jordan canonical form.

Comment: There is an algorithm stemming from the [Structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net the method in my lecture notes uses the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of an arbitrary matrix to find the Jordan canonical form. I'm sure there are other ways  but this is the only one i know about

Comment: Since your original matrix is triangular, you can write down its characteristic polynomial directly without doing any calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is the product of the minimal polynomials of each  restriction to a generalised eigenspace. So the problem comes down to  finding the minimal polynomial of a matrix with a single eigenvalue $\lambda$.

One way to find the structure of the associated Jordan matrix is to consider the following sequence of subspaces:
$$\{0\}\subset\ker(A-\lambda I)\subset\ker(A-\lambda I)^2\subset\dots\subset\ker(A-\lambda I)^r\subset\dotsm$$

This sequence first increases (strictly) and eventually stabilises. We have the following result:
$$\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^i-\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}= \text{number of Jordan blocks of size}\ge i.$$
In particular,$\dim\,\ker(A-\lambda I)$ is the total number of Jordan  blocks.

Comment: this seems like an interesting method. a side question on a less general set of matrices though, If we have any nxn matrix over a commutative ring ( which I believe means the eigenvalues are elements of a commutative ring ?) then can we always assume that it's minimal polynomial is its characteristic polynomial because of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem ?

Comment: I feel like i may be misinterpreting the Cayley-Hamilton theorem as I've been looking up examples of matrices where this doesn't seem to be the case ?

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton is also valid over a commutative ring $R$, but the notion of minimal polynomial doesn't make sense, since $R[X]$ is not a P.I.D. (polynomial ring being a P.I.D. if and only if the base ring is a field) – not even a domain unless $R$ is.